# Rename code in c have a error

Tags: c, rename

i want to move a file from a directory to anther directory with C Coding.

I search and find rename(); function , but when working it doesnt work and have a error:

my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {

 if(rename("/root/tmpfile.php", "/home/check-tmp.php"))

 perror( NULL );

 }
```

the code well compiled but when running this code showing this error:

```
Invalid cross-device link
```

How to move a file from a directory to anther directory without using System for fopen?

Aslo , i finded many codes and ways to do it but doesnt working all codes.

Please say me a way and make sure it will work

Thanks.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note269

Comment: can you say me how to do it?

Comment: Is the root user executing this program or is a non-privileged user?

Answer (score 0):

Many aspects of the behavior of `rename' are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one file system to another , it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists.

In other words, your system does not support rename files cross different partitions (your root partition and your home partition are different.)

So the solution is when it fails, copy the file to the destination and delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

The `rename` call can only rename and move files within a single disk partition.  The error "cross-device link" indicates that you attempted to move a file from one partition to another.  (If you were on a Windows system, you can imagine if you tried to rename a file from C: to D:.)

When you use the Unix `mv` command to move files, it first tries a `rename`, but if it fails in this way, it falls back and makes a new copy of the file in the new location, then deletes the original.  That's what you would have to have your code do in this situation, too.

(Copying a file is easy enough, but there are plenty of library functions out there that will do it for you, and also take care of things like preserving the last-modified time and other file attributes.)